# Trigger to prevent User From Adding more than one product to an opportunity

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

So i have written a trigger to prevent user from entering more than one opportunity product to the same opportunity, but the problem is when he adds more than one opportunity product at the same time, my trigger does not fire, salesforce takes it as one product.
What can i add to my trigger to fix this ?

My trigger :

```
trigger OpportunityLineItemBeforeInsert on OpportunityLineItem (before insert) {
    Set<Id>opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();



    // get all parent IDs

    for(OpportunityLineItem i : trigger.new)

    {

        opportunityIds.add(i.OpportunityId);

    }

    // query for related Olis (Opportunity Line Items)

    Map<Id, Opportunity> opps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT ID, 
                                                          (SELECT ID 
                                                           FROM OpportunityLineItems) 
                                                          FROM Opportunity 
                                                          WHERE ID IN :opportunityIds]);

    for(OpportunityLineItem i : trigger.new)

    {

        if(opps.get(i.OpportunityId).OpportunityLineItems.size()>0)

        {

            i.addError('Your Message');

        }

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably ignore anything related to the Oppty.

You want only one product created, so on creation, either the number of LI is 0 and you can create exactly one, or it' snot 0 and you can't create any.

I would just create a rollup field on the Oppty, count the products. If the count != 0, then fail the validation. If count = 0, then count the Olis in trigger.new and if !=1, fail.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing code to do this you should instead create a field on products that stores the id of the parent opportunity, make that field unique, and populate the value via workflow or process builder with the id of the parent opportunity.  That way if a second product gets added the unique constraint would fire and prevent the record from being inserted.

Another option would be to create a rollup on opportunity to count the number of opportunity products, then add a validation rule that show an error if the number of products > 1.  The advantage of doing it this way is that you get to set the error message as opposed to the generic duplicate  error message with the first option.